# Postfix / smtpd_relay_restrictions. How to allow relay from third party smtp server to any domains (but not open relay!)

Tags: postfix

By default, my Postfix allows relay emails sent to my domain (domain1.com) or only for password auth clients or for 'myhostname' addresses. This is a regular situation for most mail servers.

If I set up a connector in Exchange Online to send outbound emails via my postfix, clients (for example, Outlook) normally send email, using Exchange credentials, and Exchange service forward sent email to my postfix.

main.cf:

```
relay_domains = domain1.com
...
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain,
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_unverified_sender,
        reject_unknown_client_hostname,
        reject_unknown_helo_hostname,
        defer_unauth_destination
```

Postfix will deny with "454 4.7.1 Relay access denied" code:

```
Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-ve1eur122p0672.outbound.protection.outlook.com[213.199.154.150]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-ve1eur122p0672.outbound.protection.outlook.com[213.199.154.150]: 454 4.7.1 <external123@partner.org>: Relay access denied; from=<my@domain1.com> to=<external123@partner.org> proto=ESMTP helo=<EUR03-VE1-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com>
disconnect from mail-ve1eur122p0672.outbound.protection.outlook.com[213.199.154.150]
```

It's normal, because host 've1eur122p0672.outbound.protection.outlook.com' isn't in myhostname and this host not uses smtp-auth.

I tried:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain,
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/trusted_servers,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_unverified_sender,
        reject_unknown_client_hostname,
        reject_unknown_helo_hostname,
        defer_unauth_destination
```

And:

```
# less /etc/postfix/trusted_servers
.outbound.protection.outlook.com OK

# postmap /etc/postfix/trusted_servers
```

But without result.

Is it possible to allow postfix accept relaing mails from *.outbound.protection.outlook.com to any domains, but for others allow only password auth?

Answer (score -1):

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = 
       check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/trusted_servers
```

Not **smtpd_relay_restrictions** section. Please read: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#check_client_access

Comment: Not sure you are right.

Comment: option 'smtpd_client_restrictions' permit all by default. There is no need to allow additional servers.

Comment: smtpd_client_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname,
        reject_unknown_client_hostname,
        permit

Comment: if I change:
relay_domains = domain1.com,gmail.com
every can relay email from postfix to gmail without auth!

Comment: As for me, changes must be in "smtpd_recipient_restrictions" or "smtpd_relay_restrictions".

Comment: Like task: I can be able to send email both with password auth AND from current servers (my case: exchange). This is no client restrictions. This is permission who able to send email from my postfix.

Comment: Александр, я совсем в английский ушел. Только сейчас присмотрелся к вашему ФИО...

Comment: serverfault is international, keep going to use English ;)

Comment: In your case I can recomend you to add outlook.com to $mynetwork

Comment: Mail sent from random hosts (and IP addrs)  *.outbound.protection.outlook.com. For example, mail-ve1eur122p0672.outbound.protection.outlook.com. Each time - new host from MS... I don't sure that it is good idea to try to parse all hosts which MS can use... Ok, I think will be better to use IMAP and custom SMTP.

Comment: But: strange: why isn't posiible to allow postfix to relay mail to any domains in internet ONLY from 1) "*.outbound.protection.outlook.com" AND 2) password auth clients. Very strange...

Comment: You don't need to parse, outlook provies them: https://mail.live.com/mail/ipspace.aspx . And  yes, it's unsafe. But use whilelist of hosts is not better.

Comment: Also try to check http://www.postfix.org/addon.html. Perhaps you will find a plugin that will allow you to customize your postfix behavior

Comment: Thank you for links, useful. But agree with you, it's too not safe, really.

Comment: You are wrong. From official README: `The problem is that Postfix versions before 2.10 did not have smtpd_relay_restrictions. They combined the mail relay and spam blocking policies, under smtpd_recipient_restrictions. The result is that a permissive spam blocking policy could unexpectedly result in a permissive mail relay policy.`
http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html